# The method raw() from the type Result is deprecated

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop-yarn

In our latest upgrade of our CDH Cluster we have come accross many methods and classes which have been made deprecated.

One such case is the method raw() which I was using to get the epochTimestamp out of our Hbase table records as shown below:

`String epochTimestamp = String.valueOf(values.raw()[0].getTimestamp());`

My PM has asked me to get rid of all such deprecated functions and replace the same with latest.

From https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html I found that listCells is the equivalent of raw(), but can anyone help me with how to obtain the epochTimestamp from HBase record using listCells?

Comment: Did you try `values.listCells().get(0).getTimestamp()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html):

> public List listCells()

Create a sorted list of the Cell's in this result.
Since HBase 0.20.5 this is equivalent to raw().

Thus your code should look:

```
String epochTimestamp = String.valueOf(values.listCells().get(0).getTimestamp());
```

Comment: Thanks Max, started coding again after 2 years of break, I can't even remember half of java tips and tricks :(

Answer (score 4):

A replacement for

```
raw()
```

could be to iterate over:

```
result.listCells()
```

Which gives you a cell, and then to get the value, use:

```
CellUtil.cloneValue(cell)
```

See the documentation:

https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/CellUtil.html

**Example:**

```
for (Cell cell : result.listCells()) {
    String row = new String(CellUtil.cloneRow(cell));
    String family = new String(CellUtil.cloneFamily(cell));
    String column = new String(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(cell));
    String value = new String(CellUtil.cloneValue(cell));
    long timestamp = cell.getTimestamp();
    System.out.printf("%-20s column=%s:%s, timestamp=%s, 
        value=%s\n", row, family, column, timestamp, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to get all columns and values, u can use CellUtil like below:

```
    List<Cell> cells = listCells();

    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (Cell c : cells) {

        result.put(Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(c)),Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneValue(c)));

    }
```